# Find & Xargs copy and rename via bash script

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, find, xargs

I have a folder with images and I need to copy them elsewhere removing special chars in the progress.
Lets say I have this

```
Folder1/ImageÑ%1.jpg
Folder1/ImageÑ%1-70x70.jpg
Folder1/ImageÑ%2.jpg
Folder1/ImageÑ%2-70x70.jpg
Folder1/ImageÑ%3.jpg
Folder1/ImageÑ%3-100x100.jpg
Folder1/ImageÑ%4.jpg
Folder1/ImageÑ%4-100x100.jpg
```

And I want to copy just the files that doesn't have "-70x70" or "-100x100" in the name to Folder2 and be like this (without any special char):

```
Folder2/Image1.jpg
Folder2/Image2.jpg
Folder2/Image3.jpg
Folder2/Image4.jpg
```

I've managed to copy the files, but I have no clue how to rename the files (and remove the special chars) in the same step. I think it's using SED but I can't figure out how.

```
find Folder1 -type f -regextype posix-extended \( ! -regex '.+\-[0-9]{2,4}x[0-9]{2,4}\.jpg' \) -print0 |  xargs -0 cp -p --target-directory=Folder2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This maybe works for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=/your/Folder1
DEST=/your/Folder2

for f in `ls -1 $DIR | grep .jpg | egrep -v ".+\-[0-9]{2,4}x[0-9]{2,4}\.jpg"`
do
        f=$(basename $f)
        F=$(echo "$f" | sed "s/[^A-Z|a-z|0-9|\.]//g;")
        cp -p "$DIR/$f" "$DEST/$F"
done
```

You can use MV instead of CP if you needit.

**EDITED**

This will get only the files you have to copy:

```
ls -1 $DIR/*.jpg | egrep -v ".+\-[0-9]{2,4}x[0-9]{2,4}\.jpg
```

**basename** command get only the file name in order to replace weir characters and prepare to move
**sed** it's replacing all character if the aren't letters and numbers (and a dot for file extension)

Answer (score 4):

To remove weird characters, I recommend you [detox](http://detox.sourceforge.net/)

Then :

```
find Folder1 \( ! -name 'Image*-70x70*' -a ! -name 'Image*-100x100*' \) |
    xargs -i% cp -p % Folder2
```

**edit**

find explanations :

- the `!` character is a *negation*
- `-a` option is a `AND` condition
- the parenthesis are there to enclose the conditions

**Edit2**

To do it on the fly like you ask (for substituting weird characters):

```
find Folder1 \( ! -name 'Image*-70x70*' -a ! -name 'Image*-100x100*' \) \
    -exec bash -c '
        file=$(echo "$1" | perl -pe "s/\303\221%/_weird_/g")
        cp -p "$1" "Folder2/$file"
    ' -- {} \;
```

Comment: Edited mistake on find option

Comment: Is it possible to run detox in the same step? I mean I can't rename files from Folder1

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
for file in Folder1/*.jpg; do
  case $file in
    *-70x70.jpg | *-100x100.jpg) ;;
    *) cp "$file" "Folder2/Image${file#Folder1/Image?}" ;;
  esac
done
```

The construct `${variable#pattern}` removes any match for `pattern` from the beginning of the value of `$variable`.  The pattern `Folder1/Image?` matches the literal text `Folder1/Image` (we prepend back the static `Image` part then) and one arbitrary character.

If the offending character is not a single byte, try doubling the question mark for a start; that will match two arbitrary characters (or bytes, if your locale etc are configured that way). If you have a combining Unicode sequence, it takes much more than that, though -- a hex dump of the actual bytes used to represent the file name would be helpful for diagnosing this.  Anyway, you can simply trim from the other end instead, although that gets a bit more involved;

```
  *) base=${file#Folder1/}
     prefix=${base%%[0-9]*}
     cp "$file" "Folder2/Image${base#$prefix}" ;;
```

The variant `${variable%pattern}` trims from the end instead of the beginning, and doubling the `#` or `%` causes the shell to trim the longest possible match instead of the shortest.  (I believe the longest-possible matching is a Bash extension?)

Comment: Nope, the weird character is still present in Folder2. Fail.

Comment: Works for me.  But I edited my answer; perhaps it works for you now?